# How to configure spring batch job to run parallelly without considering the other set of jobs?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

i am working in the spring-batch where i am having one situation

we have 2 set of schedulers

```
public class SchedulerA {

    @Autowired
    private Job a;

    @Autowired
    private Job b;

    @Autowired
    private Job c;

    @Autowired
    private Job d;

    @Autowired
    private SpringBatchJobHandler springBatchJobHandler;

   @Autowired
   private JobHandler jobHandler;

    private List<String> jobName = new ArrayList<>();

   @Bean
  public void SchedulerLoad() {
    jobName.add(a.getName());
    jobName.add(b.getName());
    jobName.add(c.getName());
    jobName.add(d.getName());
 }

  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000)
    private void jobScheduler() throws Exception {
        for (String job : jobName) {
            if (!jobHandler.isJobForceStopped()) {
                springBatchJobHandler.runJob(job);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the second set of scheduler

```
  public class SchedulerB {
    
        @Autowired
        private Job q;
    
        @Autowired
        private Job w;
    
        @Autowired
        private Job e;
    
        @Autowired
        private Job r;

        @Autowired
        private SpringBatchJobHandler springBatchJobHandler;

       @Autowired
       private JobHandler jobHandler;

        private List<String> jobName = new ArrayList<>();

       @Bean
      public void SchedulerLoad() {
        jobName.add(q.getName());
        jobName.add(w.getName());
        jobName.add(e.getName());
        jobName.add(r.getName());
     }
    
      @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000)
        private void jobScheduler() throws Exception {
            for (String job : jobName) {
                if (!jobHandler.isJobForceStopped()) {
                    springBatchJobHandler.runJob(job);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now what we are trying is jobs within the each scheduler will run in sequential mode but both scheduler class will parallely.

Ex: Both schedulerA and schedulerB has to run at same time parallely, But the jobs within the respective classes has to be run in sequential mode only.

is that possible to achieve the above scenario?

i know above question will be so much confusing but we dont have any other choice..!!

please share your feedback for this situation..

Answer (score 0):

There are two `TaskExecutor`s involved in your scenario:

1. The one used by Spring Batch to run jobs when launched via a `JobLauncher`. By default, this uses a `SyncTaskExecutor` which runs submitted jobs in the calling thread. If you use the default `JobLauncher` in your `SpringBatchJobHandler`, then your jobs will be run in sequence since you submit them in a for loop.
2. The one used by Spring Boot to run scheduled tasks. By default, this one has a pool size of 1, see [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-task-execution-scheduling): `The thread pool uses one thread by default and those settings can be fine-tuned using the spring.task.scheduling namespace.` This means if you schedule two tasks to run at the same time as in your use case, they will be run in sequence by the same thread.

Now If you want to run those scheduled tasks in parallels using different threads, you need to increase the pool size of the `TaskExecutor` configured by Spring Boot  to 2 or more. You can do that by setting the following property:

```
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=2
```